# Is it possible to use Linq with OrmLite?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We have a system with several apps written in C# under .Net 4.0. One of the apps is a server that handles object persistence to a Ms SQL Server Express Db by sending objects to/from the other apps via WCF. The server app uses Linq queries to get data from the Db. Now we want to get rid of SQL-Server and instead use PostgreSQL for the Db.

We think we will be able to use OrmLite to handle the inferface between our objects ant the Postgres Db.

The question is, how can we use Linq to query the Postgres Db if we use OrmLite?

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#new-strong-typed-sql-expression-api ?

Comment: Yes, I have. I thought we would miss Linq, but maybe those functions and others will do. By the way, where is all the documentation we need to make full use of this library? I have had a quick look at the source and there is obviously tons of potentially useful functionality that have no documentation and no usage examples. What a pity, because this otherwise seems like a great product. But without documentation, how can we use it?

Comment: There is this API overview: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#api-overview . And the documentation is very thorough, one other good place to look are at the tests: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/tree/master/tests